# vertical align image in smaller container

Tags: html, css, dom, width

I have a container which is 100px by 100px. I have put an image in it which I don't know the dimensions, except the fact that I have set the width to 100px. I would like to find a way in CSS to vertically align this image middle in it's container. I have stuck overflow:hidden on the container to prevent it from showing anything outside the square.

I have found something on here on how to do the opposite (width, not height).

Comment: vertically align it how? top, bottom, center, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the image inside two divs that will mimic an html table. The outer div will have `display: table` property, and the inner will have `display: table-cell` property. You can set the `vertical-align` property of the inner div to be top, middle, or bottom.

HTML:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="table-cell middle">
        <img src="https://www.google.ca/images/srpr/logo3w.png" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
}
.middle {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

[Here's the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/JnESs/3/)

Comment: You can do `table-row` instead of `table`, and apply the styles to the cell itself for more of a "traditional" design, since this smells like a thumbnail grid, and there will probably be more than one image. http://jsfiddle.net/JnESs/4/ It also works really well with a `ul` implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/JnESs/6/

Comment: This doesn't work anymore (Chrome 52.0.2743.116 m). `overflow:hidden` does nothing on elements with `display:table`.

Comment: @Fernando This question and answer is about vertical align, it doesn't have anything to do with `overflow:hidden`... ?

Comment: Might be that the question was edited after your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to know the height of the image to vertically align it as you would then use this CSS:

```
div {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

div img {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-XXXpx /*(where XXX px is half the height of the image)*/
}
```

Comment: I don't know the height of the image.

Comment: Could you maybe use a simple bit of javascript/jquery to get the height then apply it?